# How to make a join with dplyr package with "by" containing mathematical operation

Tags: r, dplyr

I had a look over all the forum and did not find what I was looking for.

Let's take as an example a database containing years:

```
dplyr::storms

name   year month   day  hour   lat  long status              category  wind pressure tropicalstorm_force_… hurricane_force…
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>               <ord>    <int>    <int>                 <int>            <int>
 1 Amy    1975     6    27     0  27.5 -79   tropical depression -1          25     1013                    NA               NA
 2 Amy    1975     6    27     6  28.5 -79   tropical depression -1          25     1013                    NA               NA
 3 Amy    1975     6    27    12  29.5 -79   tropical depression -1          25     1013                    NA               NA
 4 Amy    1975     6    27    18  30.5 -79   tropical depression -1          25     1013                    NA               NA
 5 Amy    1975     6    28     0  31.5 -78.8 tropical depression -1          25     1012                    NA               NA
 6 Amy    1975     6    28     6  32.4 -78.7 tropical depression -1          25     1012                    NA               NA
 7 Amy    1975     6    28    12  33.3 -78   tropical depression -1          25     1011                    NA               NA
 8 Amy    1975     6    28    18  34   -77   tropical depression -1          30     1006                    NA               NA
 9 Amy    1975     6    29     0  34.4 -75.8 tropical storm      0           35     1004                    NA               NA
10 Amy    1975     6    29     6  34   -74.8 tropical storm      0           40     1002                    NA               NA
# … with 11,849 more rows
```

I would like to make a left join with "year" column as key for the operation, but in the format "year+1" to bring the info for the next year for each row

So basically:

```
Joint= storms %>% left_join(storms, by=c("name",year+1="year"))
```

Is there an easy way to do it or I have inevitably to create the column year+1 before making the left_join?

Thank you

Comment: Is the storm Zeta (2005 and 2006) spreading across 2 different years? Is Ten (2005, 2007, 2011), for example, different storms that were took the same name?

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to illulstrate this with a minimal example so we will use `BOD` which comes with R.

With the current version of dplyr you would have to create a new column but this could be done with sqldf in the pipeline.  Omit the line that ends in -- if you don't want Time 2 to appear.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sqldf)

BOD %>% 
  { sqldf("select 
     a.* 
     , b.Time Time2 -- 
     , b.demand demand2
    from [.] a
    left join [.] b on a.Time + 1 = b.Time") 
  }
##   Time demand Time2 demand2
## 1    1    8.3     2    10.3
## 2    2   10.3     3    19.0
## 3    3   19.0     4    16.0
## 4    4   16.0     5    15.6
## 5    5   15.6    NA      NA
## 6    7   19.8    NA      NA
```

We could also use `match`

```
library(dplyr)
BOD %>%
  mutate(Time2 = Time + 1, demand2 = demand[match(Time2, Time)])
##   Time demand Time2 demand2
## 1    1    8.3     2    10.3
## 2    2   10.3     3    19.0
## 3    3   19.0     4    16.0
## 4    4   16.0     5    15.6
## 5    5   15.6     6      NA
## 6    7   19.8     8      NA
```

or if you don't want Time2 then

```
library(dplyr)
BOD %>%
  mutate(demand2 = demand[match(Time + 1, Time)])
##   Time demand demand2
## 1    1    8.3    10.3
## 2    2   10.3    19.0
## 3    3   19.0    16.0
## 4    4   16.0    15.6
## 5    5   15.6      NA
## 6    7   19.8      NA
```